# Ambiguous argument in git reset

Tags: git, version-control

I recently screwed up a `git rebase -i`, and so I wanted to do a `git reset --hard HEAD@{5}`.

However, doing a `git reset --hard HEAD@{5}` or `git log HEAD@{5}` caused the following error message to be shown:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD@{5}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Then, I decided to specify the hash key corresponding to `HEAD@{5}` shown in `git reflog` instead.  For instance:

```
git reset --hard e8be841
```

In doing so, was there any risk screwing up the git repository or doing something unexpected?

Comment: For future reference `git rebase --abort` is a good way to jump out of a rebase operation.

Comment: Thanks, but the git rebase -i had already been committed. I believe "git rebase --abort is for abandoning a rebase that hasn't been completed - either because there were conflicts or because it was interactive or both".  I should have clarified this in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is very forgiving in how it does merges and rebases. If you look at the git repository's file structure during one of those operations, you will see that it alters files designated to help with those operations and does not unsafely change core objects. If it does, it's in an additive manner.

So there is practically no chance of doing any damage to your repository. As an example, take another repo, make a copy, start a rebase and then compare the .git folders in both.

P.S. as per the comment on your question, yes, do use `git rebase --abort`

Comment: Thanks very much, Adam, for your response.  What I didn't understand was why "git reset --hard HEAD@{5}" gave an ambiguity error message, where as "git reset --hard e8be841" executed fine without error.  The hash "e8be841" corresponded to the same entry as HEAD@{5} in the git reflog.

Comment: There may have been some corruption in your case.. did you not mistake HEAD%{5} for yourbranch@{5}?

Comment: My "git reflog" only shows entries that contain HEAD@{X}.  So my git reset specified either the HEAD@{X} or the corresponding hash.  How could git have been corrupted?  Thanks.

Comment: it's very strange that you would get an error using HEAD@{5} and then use the hash that reflog has and not get that error. Have you peeked at the contents of reflog with an editor? The file is in the .git folder...

Comment: I've looked at .git/logs/refs/heads.  But I don't see any obvious sign that something is corrupt...

Answer (score 16):

For me the problem was I needed to put the double quotes on **Windows command prompt**.

Instead of:

```
git reset --soft 'HEAD^'
```

I had to write:

```
git reset --soft "HEAD^"
```

Comment: I also needed to do this in order to use similar commands in powershell. e.g. in Windows 10 `git diff HEAD@{8}` worked fine in command prompt but I had to use `git diff "HEAD@{8}"` in powershell.

Comment: That is helpful! I just spent an hour trying to understand the "ambiguous argument" error but now it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Git has some shell argument quoting issues.

Try `git log 'HEAD@{5}'` instead.

In my case I get the error `fatal: Log .git/logs/HEAD is empty.`.

The next workaround for this is:

`git log HEAD^^^^^`
.